# Homomorphism between character groups

Tags: representation-theory, characters

Actually, this question came from the exercise (Cp.10 Q5.7) in the Artin's "Algebra". The question is that:

- Let $\phi:G\to G'$ be a homomorphism between of abelian groups. Define an induced homomorphism $\hat{\phi}:\hat{G'}\to \hat{G}$ between their character groups. And prove that if $\phi$ is injective, then $\hat{\phi}$ is surjective, and conversely.

I know the induced homomorphism is: $\hat{\phi}(\chi')=\chi'\circ \phi$, and know how to prove if $\phi$ is surjective then $\hat{\phi}$ is injective (but this is not the question asking for).

I tried some approaches of proving the last part, but still not yet finished. Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: So given a map $\psi$ from $G$ to $\mathbb{C}$ you want to find a map $\psi'$ from $G'$ to $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\psi = \widehat{\phi}(\psi')$. To do this, you need to specify what it should do to each element in $G'$. Try to write up what this should be and you should hopefully see at some point that this will in fact make sense precisely because $\phi$ is injective.

Comment: I've tried this method, but it seems it doesn't work unless phi is an isomorphism, while do you mean for the other elements not in phi(G), we let that character equals to 1 on these elements?

Comment: Still didn't figure out how to do the next step, any ideas are welcome!